# How to get images of products in cart using rest API

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api

Doing a request to "V1/guest-carts/666ef786077b70c95016727cfaf21830/items" will give:

```
[
  {
    "item_id": 129,
    "sku": "24-UG05",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "Go-Get'r Pushup Grips",
    "price": 19,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "75fc406b9aadbad6fe1b9a2df9881acd"
  },
  {
    "item_id": 131,
    "sku": "24-WG03",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "Clamber Watch",
    "price": 54,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "75fc406b9aadbad6fe1b9a2df9881acd"
  }
]
```

But I also need the thumbnails for the products.. how can I get them without making extra requests for each product?

Comment: did you get a solution for this? We need the same.

Comment: @mshakeel yeah we did custom API´s for the site..

Comment: Thank you Mackelito. We have also added a simple api call and simply returned CartItems[] array which have all information with images as well. Can you please share your implementation as answer so it can benefit others as well.

Comment: I dont work on that company any more and dont have the source.. even if I did I doubt I would be allowed to :(

Comment: hi @Mackelito may i know whether you got the solution for this please confirm thanks